# tumblr theme, with photosets fitting whole screen

Tags: html, css, tumblr

tldr: I want to create simple theme, based on 2 columns with just pictures, that fill the whole screen, like this - http://half-way.precrafted.com/

Hello.

I started learning html/css yesterday, because i want to create rather simple theme that would fit my needs.

However, it turned out to be harder than i thought, unfortunately.

I post only pictures, without any captions or tags. All i want is theme based on 2 grids, where whole screen is occupied with pictures (except header on top). This is the best, almost exact example of what i want - http://half-way.precrafted.com/

However, the issue is that tumblr allows photoset with maximum width of 700px. This may be overriden with javascript - and i found such scripts, but it uses fixed values, so it won't really fit to any screen - just mine.

Comment: How are you displaying these photosets? On one of the grids? Or an image on each side? I'm assuming it's the former I just need to be sure before I can figure out the issue.

Comment: When styling the images inside the photoset, try `width: [yoursize] !important;` That should override any other styles.

Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13060492/1888402

Comment: like that - http://atnightwerise.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Set the photosetrow class to:

```
<div class="photoset_row photoset_row_2">
```

The CSS for this:

```
width: 400px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 10px;

.photoset .photoset_row .photoset_photo:first-child {
margin-left: 0 !important;
}
.photoset .photoset_row .photoset_photo {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I literally pulled that CSS from looking at the source code of that page you posted.

It seems the most important one is the `photoset_row_2`